# data migration stage - step: map step

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate and got the following:

```
[2018-06-17 01:19:50][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2018-06-17 01:19:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step:Customer Attributes Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2018-06-17 01:19:53][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
83% [=======================>----] Remaining Time: 18 secsKilled
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: check error log

Comment: thanks @MagenX I can't find an error.log, I have migration.log (which looks like the migration data that was in shell) as well as debug.log, that has no information regarding the error.